# Missing Steps in Proving $\tan\theta=u/|\lambda|$ for Ruled Surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading Do Carmo's Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces 2nd Edition and am on page 195. In the section on ruled surfaces, he says

> The normal vector to the surface at (t,u) is
>
> $N(t,u)=\frac{\textbf{x}_t \wedge \textbf{x}_u}{|\textbf{x}_t\wedge\textbf{x}_u|}=\frac{\lambda w'+uw' \wedge w}{\sqrt{\lambda^2+u^2}|w'|}.$
>
> On the other hand $(\lambda\ne 0)$,
>
> $N(t,0) = \frac{w'}{|w'|}\frac{\lambda}{|\lambda|}.$
>
> Therefore, if $\theta$ is the angle formed by $N(t,u)$ and $N(t,0)$,
>
> $\tan\theta=\frac{u}{|\lambda|}.$

I'm not able to derive the last line and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given enough information, and I do not have the book to look it up. However, since I believe I know what's going on here, we have $|w|=1$ and so $w'$ is orthogonal to $w$ and $w'/|w'|\wedge w$ is a unit vector orthogonal to $w'$.

Assume $\lambda>0$ (I'll let you worry about the other case). The angle $\theta$ to which doCarmo refers is an angle in a right triangle for which the opposite side is $u/\sqrt{\lambda^2+u^2}$ and the adjacent side is $\lambda/\sqrt{\lambda^2+u^2}$. Thus, $\tan\theta$ is their ratio, namely $u/\lambda$.